# What is a bookmark column in a database?

Tags: sql-server, database

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for **SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable** method states the following for the returned **ColumnOrdinal**:

> "The ordinal of the column. This is zero for the bookmark column of the row, if any. Other columns are numbered starting with one. This column cannot contain a null value."

But what does it mean by bookmark column? Is it like the primary key?

In the end, what I would like to know is if ColumnOrdinal will always be zero based or if there are scenarios when it would not be zero based.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bookmarks, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131492%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> Bookmarks let consumers quickly return
>   to a row. With bookmarks, consumers
>   can access rows randomly based on the
>   bookmark value. **The bookmark column is
>   column 0 in the rowset.** The consumer
>   sets the dwFlag field value of the
>   binding structure to
>   DBCOLUMNSINFO_ISBOOKMARK to indicate
>   that the column is used as a bookmark.
>   The consumer also sets the rowset
>   property DBPROP_BOOKMARKS to
>   VARIANT_TRUE. This lets column 0 be
>   present in the rowset. The
>   IRowsetLocate::GetRowsAt method is
>   then used to fetch rows, starting with
>   the row specified as an offset from a
>   bookmark.

Comment: So, does this mean that ColumnOrdinal will always start at zero? Will a bookmark column always be present?

Comment: I *believe* a bookmark column is only present with a non-clustered index as the bookmark is used as a lookup into the clustered index. When it is present it will always be column zero of the rowset.

Comment: But Yuck, something as simple as this will have a ColumnOrdinal of zero: "SELECT 1 AS Dummy1". How is that related to indexes?